# Infrastructure for audio-video chat

Tags: video, streaming, chat, rtp

We are building a web application which allows the user to consult a tech support expert while using the application. The interaction will involve audio-video chat using the webcam and also, screen-sharing whereby the user's browser can be seen by the tech support expert over the internet.
If we have to build this from scratch, what servers do we require? Do we need a streaming server or an RTP server?
Can this be done using .NET WCF?

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: Similar more recent question on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353575/video-conferencing-in-net